# Cannot call method 'reload' of undefined jQuery error

Tags: jquery

My jQuery keeps chucking this error up - 'Cannot call method 'reload' of undefined'.

I basically want the parent page to reload after 8 Seconds (this is synced to refresh once the colorbox closes)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#success').trigger('click');
});
var t=setTimeout(parent.$.fn.colorbox.close,8000);
var s=setTimeout(parent.location.reload(),8000);
</script>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you add `alert(parent.location);` to the line above where you define `s`, what does it show?

Comment: What's `parent`? Can you post the place where it is defined?

Comment: Using that it shows - host: "localhost:8888"
hostname: "localhost"
href: "http://localhost:8888/?page=profile&id=49"

Answer (score 1):

This is not a jQuery error at all, parent.location is simply 'undefined'. It probably became undefined after the first refresh. This is a bad way of programming for the web and will not be supported cross-platform (f.i., macs use the "opener" property of windows for this).

Answer (score 0):

1. This has nothing to do with jQuery. It's a javascript error.
2. This is incorrect:

   var s=setTimeout(parent.location.reload(),8000);

`setTimeout()` accepts either a string or function reference for the 1st arg, and I doubt that the reload function returns a function.

You may be able to get away with:

```
var s=setTimeout(parent.location.reload,8000);
```

But you'll most likely need to do:

```
var s=setTimeout(function(){parent.location.reload();},8000);
```

\3. Use your debugger to see what value `parent` and/or `parent.location` actually is.

Comment: Parent.location returns 

host: "localhost:8888"
hostname: "localhost"
href: "http://localhost:8888/?page=profile&id=49"

Its the 'href' I want to refresh it on! Neither the above worked by the way, the error is Cannot call method 'reload' of undefined